# Doesn't open software updater on ubuntu 14.10

Tags: launcher, update-manager

It's showing in the launcher the software updater. That means it has new updates.

But i press it and can't open it! The only thing i can do is right click and install updates, or close it and go from the dash and reopen it.

But of course from the terminal it's working perfect.

But why doesn't open from the launcher when it pops up with new updates? and how can i fix it?

Edit:

I tried also to update the manager via the terminal:

> Sudo update-manager

But it gets me the error.

> Failed to download the repository information. Check your Internet connection.

I don't know if these 2 are linked.

Comment: I've had the same issue the last few days :( did you manage to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

You can right click on the icon in the launcher to close it. Then you can load it from the start menu by typing in 'updater'. For me this loaded it up properly, although it's the second day in a row it's done this so not sure if it's a permanent fix...